# data rearrangement in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

I have the following code

```
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(1:5,1:5);
z=X1.^2+Y1.^2
[X2,Y2]=meshgrid([1 2 3 3.5 4 5],[1 2 3 3.5 4 5]);
z2=interp2(X1,Y1,z,X2,Y2)
mesh(X2,Y2,z2)
```

Is there any way to stucture data such as command mesh(z2) would produce the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but you could certainly cut out a few lines in your code to do the same thing:

```
[X2,Y2]=meshgrid([1 2 3 3.5 4 5],[1 2 3 3.5 4 5]);
z2=X2.^2+Y2.^2;
mesh(X2,Y2,z2);
```

Or, you could just do:

```
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(1:5,1:5);
z=X1.^2+Y1.^2;
mesh(z);
```

For this particular example, I don't think you will see much of a difference between the two methods.